# Using variable in django queryset in a filter or empty the filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Question 1. how could I use a variable in this queryset,

```
def function(request):
    qset1 = BigTable.objects.values(
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code',
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code_name',
        ).filter(id_nr_f__ie_code__unomer_f__nomer=iteration_result,
        )
```

I mean something like that

```
def function(request):

    x1 = 'id_nr_f__ie_code__unomer_f__nomer'

    qset1 = BigTable.objects.values(
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code',
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code_name',
        ).filter(x1 = iteration_result,
        )
```

Question 2.
How can I empty the filter with a varianbe, so the the filter in the query does not filter the records. I mean something like that

```
def function(request):

    x1 = 'id_nr_f__ie_code__unomer_f__nomer'
    x2 = True

    qset1 = BigTable.objects.values(
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code',
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code_name',
        ).filter(x1 = x2,
        )
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can define a `dict`, then pass it to `filter` as `kwargs`

```
attr1 = 'some attr'
attr2 = 'some attr'
filter_dict = {
    attr1:filter1,
    attr2:filter2,
     ...
}
queryset.filter(**filter_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a `Q` object where you pass a 2-tuple you aim to filter:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def function(request):

    x1 = 'id_nr_f__ie_code__unomer_f__nomer'

    qset1 = BigTable.objects.values(
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code',
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code_name',
    ).filter(
        Q((x1, iteration_result))
    )
```

or with a value:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def function(request):

    x1 = 'id_nr_f__ie_code__unomer_f__nomer'
    x2 = True

    qset1 = BigTable.objects.values(
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code',
        'deb_nr_f__dcountry__wcode_f__code_name',
    ).filter(
        Q((x1, x2))
    )
```